# StructureMap Registries in Unit Test Projects: No default Instance is registered

Tags: c#, structuremap

Using StructureMap...

I have a series of assemblies & a single IoC entry-point within the BUSINESS layer wherein I define my `ContainerRegistry` like so:

**BUSINESS.DLL REGISTRY:** 
The **WorkflowProvider** class lives in its' own library.  As such, I am passing-in the BUSINESS LAYERS assembly into the **WorkflowProvider** so it can "find" certain (expected) classes within the BUSINESS LAYER dynamically.

```
// I have simplified this class for the question
public ContainerRegistry()
{
    Scan(
        scan =>
        {
            scan.TheCallingAssembly();
            scan.WithDefaultConventions();
            scan.LookForRegistries();
            scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(f => f.FullName.StartsWith("My.Awesome.Application", true, null));
            scan.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IWorkflowProvider));
            scan.SingleImplementationsOfInterface();
        });

    For<IWorkflowProvider>().Use<WorkflowProvider>()
        .Ctor<Assembly>().Is(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
}
```

**THE EXCEPTION:** 
Now, I want to write a set of Unit Tests for all assemblies - including the BUSINESS & WORKFLOW assemblies.  However, when I try to create an instance of the **WorkflowProvider** I am getting the following exception:

```
var container = IoC.Initialize();
var workflowProvider = container.GetInstance<WorkflowProvider>()
```

> No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically
>   determined for type 'System.Reflection.Assembly'

**THE GOAL:** 
Additionally, when I use the BUSINESS LAYERS `ContainerRegistry` from the Unit Test project I want to substitute the UnitTest Assembly in this part of the mapping:

```
For<IWorkflowProvider>().Use<WorkflowProvider>()<br/>
   .Ctor<Assembly>().Is(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

**QUESTIONS:**

- Does the Unit Test project also need its' own Registry?
- And, if so, what does it look like?
- And, if so, how do I consume 2 registries in 1 project?
- How do I substitute the GetExecutingAssembly portion?
- What is the right approach here?

Hopefully, I am explaining this right.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only solution I have found.  I am hoping someone else will come up with a better solution.

```
var args = new ExplicitArguments();
args.Set<Assembly>(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

var container = IoC.Initialize();
var workflowProvider = container.GetInstance<WorkflowProvider>(args);
```